# Is it possible to write comments directly on page?

Tags: php, jquery, comments

I found some  php - jQuery code for creating commenting system.
So, comments are stored in a database, that must be read each time the page is loaded.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $comments[] = new Comment($row);
}

foreach($comments as $c){
    echo $c->markup();
}
```

Is it possible to write the comments not into database, but in a page directly, so they become the integrated part of the page ?

I can insert the comment using jQuery .insert() function and comments is there, but on refreshing, of course - it is lost.

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions will be deprecated in PHP 5.5. It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: To answer you question : Yes you can. But I would prefer using mysql ...

Comment: Where are you suggesting the comment is stored? In the php file of the page? On that user's local computer? On the server somewhere other than the database?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you want to do this?  There are a whole host of problems you would likely encounter.  1) If users are modifying your PHP files, they can add PHP code.  This could allow them to arbitrarily run server-side code on your server.  2) How will you handle concurrency?  What if two users try to write to the file at the same time?  3) Do you ever need to manage this data?  Delete undesirable comments?  That would become a highly manual process, which would make the concurrency issue even worse.  Databases exist specifically to do what you're trying to do, why not use one?

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot. It's more clearly now for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to write the comments not into database, but in a page directly...

Yes. You could simply output using `echo` in PHP or with JavaScript. But as you already pointed out data will be lost on *refresh*.

You will need to use a persistent store - database, flat file, cache - if you want it to *persist* between refresh.

Depending on your use case, sessions or cookies are also options. Although not as *persistent*.

Be sure you understand the difference between [client and server side technologies](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming).

Comment: You could put a handler on the server that would update the html file with new comments. But its a poor way of storing data as it would have no structure and without good filtering, its ripe for abuse.

Comment: @datasage Writing to an html file is no more a source for abuse than writing to a database. In both cases proper security practices will need to be followed.